# Using variable as a LIKE statement for SQL query in Python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Attempting to obtain certain information from columns in a database to create .csv files. Created code to successfully query for a single row, but have to obtain the same information for each row in the database. Each category has multiple rows, therefore I have to use LIKE statement.

```
#code in python for querying and printing multiple rows for a category
data = c.execute("SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_6_fingerprints where finger like 'lt_94' ")
for row in data:
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use parameters.  For instance:

```
data = c.execute("""
SELECT x, y
       CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT) as col3,
       CAST(quality*100 as INT) as col4
FROM UTS_6_fingerprints 
WHERE finger LIKE :pattern
""", {'pattern', 'lt_94'})
```

Comment: Thank you, upon entering this I'm getting an error on this line: """, {'pattern', 'lt_94'})
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: @mattp Change to `... WHERE finger LIKE :pattern""", {'pattern', '%lt_94%'})`,